# how can I invoke css animations when reaching specific place on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm using the [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) script and so far I implemented the mechanism that invokes css animations while reaching one of the "slides", the code looks like this:

```
img{
    -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;

}
#image-one{
    z-index: 0;
}
#image-one.active{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(200px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(200px, 0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform:translate3d(200px, 0px, 0px);
    transform: translate3d(200px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

and later on in the javascript I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#fullpage').fullpage({

        'verticalCentered': false,

        'responsive': 900,

        'css3': false,

        'anchors': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],

        'navigation': true,

        'navigationPosition': 'right',

        'navigationTooltips': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],

        'menu': '#menu',
        'scrollingSpeed': 1000,
        'scrollOverflow': 'true',

        'afterLoad': function (anchorLink, index) {
            if (index == 3) {
                $('#image-one').addClass('active');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Ok, so now, after reaching slide no. 3 I'll have the animation of this element:

```
<img src="img/a.png" alt="a" id="image-one" />
```

And that works fine. However, on slide number 3 I put the plugin liquidSlider, which looks exactly like on the [default settings](http://kevinbatdorf.github.io/liquidslider/examples/page1.html) on that webpage. And on each tab I wanted to put element that animates when user turns on that correct tab. The html code for it looks like this:

```
<div class="liquid-slider" id="slider-1">
    <div>
    <div id="images">
        <img src="img/a.png" alt="a" id="image-one" />
</div>
     <div class="sometext"> 
    <h2 class="title">title1</h2><p>this image is animated when user sees it because this tab is active when user scrolls down the page</p>
      </div>
        </div>
    <div>
      <div id="images">
        <img src="img/b.png" alt="a" id="image-two" />
</div>
     <div class="sometext"> 
    <h2 class="title">title2</h2><p>how can I animate this picture when user displays that tab?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="images">
        <img src="img/c.png" alt="a" id="image-three" />
</div>
     <div class="sometext"> 
    <h2 class="title">title3</h2><p>and how can I animate this picture when user displays that tab?</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

So how should I modify my script/create the new one to animate each element when the user selects the tab it's displayed on? Thanks, guys for help!

Comment: Take a look at the liquid slider hooks: http://kevinbatdorf.github.io/liquidslider/examples/page1.html#hooks

Comment: Ok, I see there's a part `$('#slider-5-nav-ul a').each(function() {` that refers to all panels at once, but how can I invoke my changes on single panel while clicking it?

Answer (score 1):

From what I noticed, the problem is the animations are applied to all the slides at once when you hit Slide 3. You could do a simple trick (maybe a work around) to make the animation trigger again and again when you leave or enter a tab.

If you also take a look into their [Animate.css](http://kevinbatdorf.github.io/liquidslider/examples/page2.html#animate-css) page they are doing the similar thing. Remove the class 'animated' and adding it again to animate the next slide as well. You could also do this by adding it into the transition function of your slider.

(note: Transition function needs a 'this.transition();' or it just hangs there.)

I would say something like this would do the trick

```
$('.liquid-slider').liquidSlider({
  pretransition: function() {
   $('#image-one').removeClass('active');
   $('#image-two').removeClass('active');
   $('#image-three').removeClass('active');
   $('#image-one').addClass('active');
   $('#image-two').addClass('active');
   $('#image-three').addClass('active');
   this.transition();   
  }
});
```

Haven't tested the code myself. So give it a try.